# Create a new data frame column based on another data frame column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames `df1` and `df2`

```
     no  plan  current flag
0  abc1   249       30  Y/U
1  abc2   249       30    N
2  abc3   249       30  Y/D
```

and

```
      plan  offer
0     149     20
1     249     30
2     349     40
```

I want to put an extra column in `df1` such that if `df1['flag'] == 'Y/U'` it will search the next higher number in `df2['offer']` comparing `df1['current']`. Similarly, the same rule applies for a lower number, where the flag is `Y/D`. (Keep it as usual if the flag is **N**)

Expected output:

```
     no  plan  current flag   Pos
0  abc1   249       30  Y/U   40
1  abc2   249       30    N   30
2  abc3   249       30  Y/D   20
```

I tried to do it using `apply`.

```
df1['pos'] = (df1.apply(lambda x: next((z for (y, z) in zip(df2['plan'], df2['offer'])
                                            if y > x['plan'] if z > x['current']), None), axis=1))
```

But it is giving the result considering every cases 'Y/U'.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the next higher number".

Comment: @SteeleFarnsworth If you see ```df1['current']``` and ```df1['flag']```, as first value is 30 and later one is 'Y/U'. Now see ```df2['offer']```, here the next higher number (compare to 30) is  40, that is why in my expected output 0th row has ```pos``` value is 40. It depends on flag. There are three flags. If it was 'Y/D' , we will go for the number which is just less than 30 in the ```df2```, here it is 20. I hope that it is now clear.

Comment: Does the plan column in the second dataframe do not mean anything? If so there is an easier solution than using two dataframes. As far as I understand you just add a pos value using only flag and offer value. Am I correct?

Comment: @alparslanmimaroğlu Presently not using the plan column but it has some importance. If I get the column as required, I shall use merge function to df1. Kindly suggest something so that I can use two data frames.

Comment: If I understand correctly you need to join the values of df2 'offer' in ascending order in order `['Y/U','N','Y/D']` of flag in df1?

Comment: @AnuragDabas Do not consider it as ascending order. Just compare it for ```current``` and ```flag``` of df1 with ```offer``` at df2. Then I would like to create ```pos``` column of df1.

Comment: If both df's are of different length then how can you compare?

Comment: @AnuragDabas Consider it as if 'Y/U', I would see upper value at df2 than the 'current'. Same applies for other two.

Comment: @AnuragDabas I am not comparing in exact way. I am comparing value wise. I understand your question. But presently, consider this as same length.

Answer (score 1):

Without using plan you can achieve the desired result like this.
You can just use a list.

```
offers = df2['offer'].sort_values().tolist()

def assign_pos(row, offers):
    index = offers.index(row['current'])
    if row['flag'] == "N":
        row['pos'] = row['current']
    elif row['flag'] == 'Y/U':
        row['pos'] = offers[index + 1]
    elif row['flag'] == 'Y/D':
        row['pos'] = offers[index - 1]
    
    return row

df1 = df1.apply(assign_pos, args=[offers], axis=1)
```